# Trying to load to a different page based on the value in the option box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm extremely new to this, so forgive if it is super basic and my code is terrible.
I'm trying to create a form that will load onto a new page, based upon the information that is provided in the option box by the user.

I tried integrating javascript but it's not working for me.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
    function occupationfunction() {
    var rform = document.getElementById("occupation");
        if  {(value="business.html")
        location.href="bizreg.html";
        } else if {(value="actor.html")
        location.href="actorreg.html";
        } else {
        document.write"Please select an option";
    }
    }

</script>

<form method="post">
        <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Register an account</legend>
                <p>Are you a</p>
                    <select id="occupation">
                        <option value="#">Select an option</option>
                        <option value="business.html">Business</option>
                        <option value="actor.html">Actor</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" class="button" name="blogin" value="Log In"/>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable `value` in a conditional however, that value is not set anywhere in your function.

You have created the variable `rform` and assigned it the element with the `id` attribute of "occupation", which is your select input.

So if you want the selected value of that input, you want to access that variable.  Also, since it is a select input you can access it's options with `rform.options`.

To access a specific option you need to specifiy it's index,  you can use `rform.selectedIndex` to find out which index is currently selected.

So if you combine the two you get `rform.options[rform.selectedIndex]` and that will refer to the currently selected option in your select input.

Now to get the value of that we use `.value`.

Giving us `rform.options[rform.selectedIndex].value` which is what you will need to get the value set in the HTML for that option.

NOTE: if you would rather use the text inside the option (ie Business, Actor) you would use `.text` instead of `.value`.

That being said, a better way to do this would probably be to just include the redirect in your html attribute like so ...

```
<select id="occupation" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
   <option value="#">Select an option</option>
   <option value="bizreg.html">Business</option>
   <option value="actorreg.html">Actor</option>
 </select>
```

But if you don't want to mess with all that, here is your `occupationFunction()` modified to work as requested (hopefully).

```
function occupationfunction() {
    var rform = document.getElementById("occupation");
    let value = rform.options[rform.selectedIndex].value;
        if  {(value="business.html")
            location.href="bizreg.html";
        } else if {(value="actor.html")
            location.href="actorreg.html";
        } else {
            document.write"Please select an option";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I wasn't too certain how to incorporate the variable that I defined. I don't think I outlined my issue correctly, I was trying to be redirected to a new page based upon the option that was selected in the options box.
The solution provided just appeared to stay on the same page. However, due to there only being two options, I changed the layout to just include two buttons that direct to the individual pages.
Thanks for the help though!

Comment: you might have needed to use window.location.href to fire the redirect.  not sure.  but glad you got it figured out.